# Matrices with integer coefficients

Tags: matrices

Do there exist two matrices $A,B\in\mathbb Z^{2\times 2}$, both of determinant $2$, such that $AB^{-1}\in  \mathbb Z^{2\times 2}$ but $B^{-1}A\not\in \mathbb Z^{2\times 2}$ ?

Comment: If you write something like $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}, B=\begin{pmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{pmatrix}$, you should be able to see for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 downvotes and a close vote! In fact it's a very good exercise.

If $B$ is any matrix in  $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ s.t. $\det(B)=2$, then $B^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{2}C$ where $C$ is any matrix with $\det(C)=2$ in $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

The problem becomes:
"What are the matrices $A,C \in M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ with $\det=2$ s.t. $1/2AC\in  M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $1/2CA\notin  M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ ?".

Then we consider the problem: "What are the matrices $A,C \in M_2(\mathbb{Z_2})$ with $\det=0$ s.t. $AC=0$ and $CA\not= 0$ ?".

Since $AC=0$, $A,C$ are simultaneously tringularizable and we may assume that $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{pmatrix},C=\begin{pmatrix}d&e\\0&f\end{pmatrix}$.

The required conditions are $ac=df=ad=cf=0,ae+bf=0,db+ec\not=0$.

We obtain $a=f=0,db+ec=1$. Then a solution in $M_2(\mathbb{Z_2})$ is

$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&c\end{pmatrix},C=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$; consequently, a solution in $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is

$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix},C=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: It may be a good exercise for the asker, provided the asker invests in a bit of effort, instead of asking us to do it all for him/her.  But it fails to be a good exercise for the asker when you've chosen to do the asker's work for him/her, and most likely you've complied the the asker's do my homework request.

Comment: Part 1. @amwhy , I know the argument and, very often (in particular here),  it doesn't work. Maybe you want that the OP uses the  Shuri2060's comment ! (I note that two people upvoted this comment -which is hilarious-). In fact, an idea is to use two triangular matrices and I explain what's behind this idea. Do you blame the OP for not having chosen two such matrices; clearly, if he had had this idea, then he would not have asked the question on this website ! Be serious my friend and do not play the lesson giver with me.

Comment: @amWhy ,  I did not read your comment until the end. If I read correctly, the exercise was proposed by yourself to students; if so, I understand that you are unhappy.

Answer (score 1):

Take$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\1&4\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}.$$